# Visual Composer - not working after update

Tags: visual-editor

a site has being updated to Wordpress 2.5.2 .  Since the update Visual Composer does not load, see screenshot below.  I've updated the Theme and all the plugins, including Visual Composer to the latest version.

[image]

Comment: fix the javascript errors ....

Comment: @Mark I am pretty sure there are somwhere this button in editor that switches these shortcodes to visal composer blocks editor

Comment: Search engine is a very powerful developer tool, I advice you to use it. [It seems that](http://codecanyon.net/item/visual-composer-page-builder-for-wordpress/242431/comments) it's broken for everybody, your plugin is broken. My humble advice to every _"developer"_: learn `HTML` and `CSS`, it's easy to learn, easy to use, you have full control, no redundant code and it will never break.

Comment: @Usce, I think that was the issue.  That button wasn't appearing for some reason.  It's popped up now and seems to be ok.  Thanks for your help.

Comment: @Mark No problem :)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Update Your WordPress Version to WordPress 4.5 ... Check Software Version at http://codecanyon.net/item/visual-composer-page-builder-for-wordpress/242431/support

Comment: Provide detailed info on how it solves the issue...